# boolalpha capitalize

Tags: c++

How do you capitalize the output generated by the cout of boolean values.

I know that if I did:

`cout << boolalpha << true;`

it will output

`true`

how do I get it to output

`True`

I have some feeling it has to do with do_truename and do_falsename, but I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Have you ever thought about just doing something like `cout << (true ? "True" : "False")`?

Comment: You need to say how often will you use such thing. If you need it once - use advice from Kevin Ballard or try to understand C++ Facet system

http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/25-5.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z120te3.aspx
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/numpunct/truename/

Comment: yes, but I don't want to do that everywhere I have a boolean, sometimes I want to do `cout << function("foo");` where function returns a boolean, and I have no idea ahead of time which overloaded function will be used.

Comment: Also you may use temp `string` or `sstream` object for getting particular format and then output it to `cout`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a fleeting moment I thought that this could be done using `std::uppercase` but this doesn't seem to be the case: these only apply to things like the hexadecimal digits and the exponent. So, it seems it, indeed, requires a `std::numpunct<char>` override which is, however, not that bad:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

struct numpunct
    : std::numpunct<char>
{
    std::string do_truename() const { return "True"; }
    std::string do_falsename() const { return "False"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::locale loc(std::cout.getloc(), new numpunct);
    std::cout.imbue(loc);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << true << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Question: What happens to the object created in `new numpunct`? Will it be de-allocated then the new locale object goes out of scope?

Comment: @jogojapan: I'm trying to post code behaving correctly. So, yes, the object is implicitly reference counted and it will be destroyed when the last `std::locale` referencing it goes out of scope. Since the maintenance of `std::locale` objects is somewhat implicit and they end up in quite a few places, it was felt that the object need to be automatically maintained. Since there was no `std::shared_ptr<T>` around, it uses a custom reference counting scheme.